# Powershell: Delete a file inside a folder with different name of parent folder

Tags: file, powershell, directory, get-childitem

I would like to use this option to delete those files with a specific extension (.cfg in my case) with different name of its folder. For example, if I have in a folder called MYFOLDER and inside this two files, MYFOLDER.cfg and otherfile.cfg, otherfile.cfg should be deleted (recursively).

That's all I have till now:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem * -exclude *.* -name -recurse
$file = Get-ChildItem * -include *.cfg* -name -recurse | % { [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) }
#$folder | ForEach-Object {Compare-Object $folder $file | <DELETE file with different name>}
```

How Could I make the last line?

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.cfg  | % { If ( $_.Name.Split(".")[0] -ne $_.Directory.Name ) {$_.Delete()}}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote the answer or select as the correct answer if it has solved your issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two-Liner, but you can make it to a Single liner ;)

```
$FolderName = (Get-Location).Path.Split("\")[(Get-Location).Path.Split("\").Count -1]
$Files = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne ".cfg" -or $_.Name.Split(".")[0] -ne $FolderName} | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

But this Code and also the one from Musaab Al-Okaidi doesn't handle the case, when the Name of the file contains a dot (e.g. File.Name.cfg)

Answer (score 0):

Remove -WhatIf to delete the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.cfg -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.BaseName -ne $_.Directory.Name} | 
Remove-Item -WhatIf
```